# VBA Loop Through XML Nodes Using SelectSingleNode

Tags: xml, excel, vba, loops, while-loop

I am trying to update node values in a .xml file using a loop.

The `oXMlFile.SelectSingleNode` line shown correctly updates a single node, but I don't know how to modify the code so that I can loop though all the nodes and update the values.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
oXMLFile.Load (ConfigFile)

'Update Node Attributes

Dim ii, TotChan As String
 ii = 0
 TotCh = 500

 Do While (ii < TotCh - 1)


Set CalibrationDateTimeNode=oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/HConfig/Signal[0]/CalibrationDateTime")

CalibrationDateTimeNode.Text = "2016-04-16"

 ii = ii + 1
 Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you exactly need, but to loop through xml nodes, use this:

```
Dim calibrationDateTimeNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim colNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList

Set colNodes = oXMLFile.selectNodes("/HConfig/Signal[0]/...WhateverYouNeed")
For Each CalibrationDateTimeNode In colNodes
   CalibrationDateTimeNode.Text = "2016-04-16"
Next
```

The SelectNodes command can selet a node list, and then you can iterate its elements. Using a for each makes it a lot easier than a do-while. Not to mention faster, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed and everything works now.